# RavenDB Spatial Search always empty

Tags: c#, indexing, ravendb, spatial

Im trying to find documents based on latitude and longitude so I got this:

a sample document already stored that should be found:

```js
{
    "UID": "uIwHCBvvAJ",
    "Description": "galletita",
    "Created": "03/01/2019 08:40:18",
    "Active": true,
    "Point": {
        "latitude": -37.7505796,
        "longitude": -57.4275142,
        "distanceFromMe": 0
    },
    "Shape": {
        "s": null,
        "Longitude": null
    }
}
```

Now this is the index, class and query:

```js
public class Test_Spatial40 : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Test>
    {
        public Test_Spatial40()
        {
            Map = docs => from spatial in docs
                          select new
                          {
                              Shape = spatial.Shape,
                              Point = spatial.Point,
                              _ = SpatialGenerate("Coordinates", spatial.Point.latitude, spatial.Point.longitude),
                              _2 = SpatialClustering("Clustering", spatial.Point.latitude, spatial.Point.longitude)
                          };

            Spatial(x => x.Shape, options => options.Geography.Default());
            Spatial(x => x.Point, options => options.Cartesian.BoundingBoxIndex());
        }
    }
```

```js
List<Test> r = session
                        .Query<Test, Test_Spatial40>()
                        .Customize(x => x.SortByDistance())
                        .Spatial(
                            x => x.Shape,
                            criteria => criteria
                                .WithinRadius((int)maxDist, (double)la, (double)lo))
                        .ToList();
```

```js
from spatial in docs
            select new
            {
                Shape = spatial.Shape,
                Point = spatial.Point,
                _ = SpatialGenerate("Coordinates", spatial.Point.latitude, spatial.Point.longitude),
                _2 = SpatialClustering("Clustering", spatial.Point.latitude, spatial.Point.longitude)
            };

        Spatial(x => x.Shape, options => options.Geography.Default());
        Spatial(x => x.Point, options => options.Cartesian.BoundingBoxIndex());
```

Its supposed that passing the same latirude and longitude to the query it should return results, but its empty every time... Any ideas?

Comment: nothing here..?

Answer (score 2):

In order to query it you need to have 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' in the 'Shape' field.
(If you want to query by the Shape).